# Using useState with if conditionals and return only two possible numbers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

I'm having trouble getting this to work as I want. So basically I have an input field with a 0 prefixed. I need it to return 0 if there isn't a 1 inserted (only in that case it should return 1). But I can't change the input after I write a number and console.log doesn't return only 0 or 1. This is the code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('0');

  const changeInputValue = (event) => {
    let newInput = event.target.value === "1" ? 1 : 0;
    setInputValue(newInput);
    console.log(newInput);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <label for="input1">Enter 0 or 1:</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="input1"
          value={ inputValue }
          onChange={(e) => changeInputValue(e)}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: The value of an input with number as type is a number, so you should be comparing the value to 1 not "1"

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are using '0' as a default value not 0 and '0' is a string, either use `parseInt()` or remove the quotation marks also you should convert the value of the input to a number also.
I also recommend using **htmlFor** instead of **for** in your label.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I changed to htmlFor. So now my useState is useState("0"), and I changed the set to setInputValue(parseInt(event.target.value) === 0 ? 0 : 1). The thing is, I still got the concatenation of the prefix value + 1 or 0 in my console.log. So I declared a variable and assigned it to the conditional, and that's what I put in the setInput. It kinda works

Answer (score 1):

Just change this (you initialize a string)

`const App = () => { const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('0');`

By this

`const App = () => { const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(0);`